# Escaping the parentheses - Batch File

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, escaping, psexec

I have few separate scripts which work fine separately. However, when integrated they don't work, problem is with the parentheses. I have tried online tutorials ot understand the logic behind the escaping but to no avail. Posting my small piece of code here If some one can assist me with escaping while also telling me logic to follow, as I have to integrate few more scripts as well.

```
FOR /F %%A IN (%File%) DO (
        echo %%A
    Psexec \\%%A -u %U% -p %P% ^
    cmd /c (^WHERE /r D:\ %n%^>D:\res.txt ^& ^
    FOR /f "delims=" %%X IN ^(D:\res.txt^) ^
    DO ^(del /f /a /S /Q %%X ^)) ^
    ^))
```

Comment: too much closing parantheses. Remove last line `^))` (and last `^` from the line before)

Comment: I did remove as suggested but gives the error: cmd exited on 10.10.30.116 with error code 1. 
btw last line ^)) is for the main for loop.

Comment: To encapsulate some commands within another `cmd` instance without problems, assign the full command line to a variable at the beginning and use it later (behind `cmd /C`) with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), so there is no more need to escape anything...

Comment: There is an unescaped `)` in the next-to-last line, which should be removed; and the `(^` in front of `where` is meant to be `^(`, right? Anyway, there is no need to write the output to a file, which is then parsed by `for /F`; let [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) immediately parse the output of `where`...

Comment: (^ where thing works fine, so I don't think that is creating issue. Rest your suggestion  of delayed expansion might work, I'll be looking into it. One more idea that I'll be working on, is to call each script from another in sequence, that might help to avoid escaping thing.